# Spring Metrics Collector Configuration with Spring cloud data flow docker-compose

Tags: spring-security, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have the following docker-compose.yml
I have data flow server running, kafka, zookeeper, mysql, metrics collector.

Configuration: (I provide only the dataflow-server (1.5.2 release), metrics collector)
 metrics-collector:
    image: springcloud/metrics-collector-kafka-10
    environment:
      - spring.security.user.name=spring
      - spring.security.user.password=cloud
      - spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=kafka:9092
      - spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkNodes=zookeeper:2181
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"

```
depends_on:
  - kafka
```

dataflow-server:
    image: springcloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local:${DATAFLOW_VERSION}
    container_name: dataflow-server
    ports:
      - "9393:9393"
    environment:
      - spring.cloud.dataflow.applicationProperties.stream.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=kafka:9092
      - spring.cloud.dataflow.applicationProperties.stream.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkNodes=zookeeper:2181
      - spring_datasource_url=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/dataflow
      - spring_datasource_username=root
      - spring_datasource_password=rootpw
      - spring_datasource_driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
      - spring.cloud.dataflow.metrics.collector.uri=http://172.24.173.136:8080
      - spring.cloud.dataflow.metrics.collector.username=spring
      - spring.cloud.dataflow.metrics.collector.password=cloud

However I am getting the following error:
dataflow-server      | 2018-10-01 23:15:41.370  WARN 1 --- [x-MetricStore-1] o.s.c.d.s.c.support.MetricStore          : Failure while requesting metrics from url 'http://172.24.173.136:8080/collector/metrics/streams': '401 '. Unauthorized, please provide valid credentials.

I am following this documentation link :
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-metrics-collector

What else is missing in the configuration.
The only thing that I think is might be for scdf 2.x version then are there equivalent properties in scdf 1.x 
- spring.security.user.name=spring
- spring.security.user.password=cloud

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `metrics-collector-kafka-10` [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/springcloud/metrics-collector-kafka-10/tags/) and that's on Spring Boot 1.5.x. In that Boot baseline, the security properties are different.

Please follow the 1.x version of Metrics Collector [README](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-metrics-collector/tree/v1.0.0.RELEASE#e2e-cheat-sheet) for the compatible k/v pairs.

The `master` branch of the Metrics Collector defaults to Spring Boot 2.x compatibility. If you'd like to use the 2.x version of the Metrics Collector, we have a different [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/springcloud/metrics-collector-kafka/tags/) for it, and in that release, you'd supply the creds via `spring.security.user.name` and `spring.security.user.password` properties. This change is driven by Spring Boot itself.